# Angular - Assigning mutiple Observable arrays from a Service API call

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a Service that calls an API to return an Observable `Observable<MeasuringPoint[]>`

I want to be able to subscribe multiple variables to the result of this service. Each variable MeasuringPoints$, MeasuringPointsViewed$, LatestReadings$ all want the same data, but will parse it differently. They also need to be unaware of each other.

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you share the data structure for the MeasuringPoint[] interface?

Answer (score 0):

So what I've done in the past is create an RXJS store that any component can inject and consume the data results.

**some-data-store.service.ts**

```
export class SomeDataStoreService {
  // Create a behavior subject that can be changed at will, always houses the "current" value.
  // Allows you to always get the latest emmited value.
  private _measuringPoint = new BehaviorSubject<MeasuringPoint[]>(null);

  // Expose the BeahviorSubject as an observable
  measuringPoint: Observable<MeasuringPoint[]> = this._measuringPoint.asObservable();

  // Inject your api service
  constructor(private measuringPointApi: MeasuringPointApiService) {}

  //Use Api to populate Behavior subject
  getMeasuringPoint() {
    this.measuringPointApi
      .getMeasuringPoint()
      .subscribe(data => this._measuringPoint.next(data));
  }
}
```

**some-consumer.component.ts**

```
export class SomeConsumerComponent implements OnInit {
  MeasuringPoints$: MeasuringPoint[];

  // Inject the DataStoreService
  constructor(private someDataStore: SomeDataStoreService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Request the data initially
    this.someDataStore.getMeasuringPoint();

    // Subscribe to the public member measuringPoint of the dataStoreService.
    // NOTE: You can use this piece over and over in different components, they'll just fire off whenever data is changed.
    this.someDataStore
      .measuringPoint()
      .subscribe(data => (this.MeasuringPoints$ = data));
  }
}
```

This is just an example, you'll obviously need your imports and what not, but that should get you going in the right direction. There are definitely other ways of doing this, NGRX for example https://ngrx.io/ but it's a full on state management library. I would suggest you do some more research and see if you need something as powerful as NGRX before diving into it.

Comment: thanks for the great answer @Budhead2004  One thing. I need the result to be an observable list as I use it async. I notice the MeasuringPoints$: is an array.

Comment: The data store observable returns a type of MeasuringPoint[] per your original question. I'm not sure you I understand what you mean, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I think of something like this:

```
export class ConsumerComponent implements OnInit {
    mesuringPoint$: Observable<MesurePointModel>;
    mesuringPointView$: Observable<MesurePointModelView>;
    latestReadings$: Observable<number>;

    constructor(private service: DataStoreService) {
        this.mesuringPoint$ = this.service.getData().pipe(// rxjs operators);
        this.mesuringPointView$ = this.service.getData().pipe(// rxjs operators );
        this.latestReadings$ = this.service.getData().pipe( // rxjs operators );


    ngOnInit() {
       // Subscribe here or anywhere else to your observables
       this.latestReadings$.subscribe(latestReadings => // number of latest readings)
    }


}
```

The important part is to use the RXJS for transforming or combining operators so you can create new observables that take your service's observable as an input and then pipe it so you create your own ones.

[RXJS Operators](https://www.learnrxjs.io/)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before in the following manner. Like Budhead2004 said, you should definitely do some research and find a good state management solution for your needs. This method is slightly rolled on my own, but it gets the job done for smaller apps or section of code.

Here is a stackblitz showing this in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7gjfgt

The **store.service.ts** manages the state of the data and maps the array of `MeasuringPoints` to individual observables for each point.

**store.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, BehaviorSubject, Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { MeasuringPoint } from './measuring-point';

const STUB_DATA: MeasuringPoint[] = [
  { data: 'fake data 1' },
  { data: 'fake data 2' },
  { data: 'fake data 3' },
];

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class StoreService {

  // If you receive the data as an array, you will want to store it as an array
  private _subject: Subject<MeasuringPoint[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  // Simple state management. Could switch this out for
  //  a caching library or NGRX
  private loadedData: boolean = false;

  constructor(/* inject needed services (ie. http, etc) */) { }

  // Return single MeasuringPoint objects
  public getAllMeasuringPoints$(): Observable<MeasuringPoint> {
    // If you haven't loaded the data yet, load it now
    if (!this.loadedData) {
      this._subject.next(STUB_DATA);
      this.loadedData = true;
    }

    return this._subject
      // return the observable and not the subject
      .asObservable()
      // Convert the array of MeasuringPoints to emit for each
      //  value in the array
      .pipe(
        // Log values for demonstration
        tap((values: MeasuringPoint[]) => console.log('Values before mapping: ', values)),
        // convert an observable of an array to individual observables
        mergeMap((points: MeasuringPoint[]) => from(points)),
        // Log values for demonstration
        tap((value: MeasuringPoint) => console.log('Values after mapping: ', value)),
      );
  }
}
```

You can then subscribe to the exposed method to get your data. Any component can subscribe to it. Since it is a `BehaviorSubject`, the subscriber will always get the most recent emitted value. Another thing to note about the `BehaviorSubject` is since the observable in the **store.service** is never completing, your component will need to unsubscribe when it is destroyed. Otherwise, you will have memory leaks throughout your app.

**first-component.component.ts** -- *Note: **second-component.component.ts** is pretty much a duplicate of this*

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { StoreService } from './store.service';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MeasuringPoint } from './measuring-point';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first-component',
  template: `
    <h3>First Component</h3>
    <div *ngFor="let point of measuringPoints">
      {{point | json}}
    </div>
  `
})
export class FirstComponentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public measuringPoints: MeasuringPoint[] = [];
  // Keep track of subscriptions
  private _endSubscriptions: Subject<null> = new Subject();

  constructor(private _storeService: StoreService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._storeService.getAllMeasuringPoints$()
    // This is to avoid memory leaks by unsubscribing when your component destroys
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._endSubscriptions))
    .subscribe((point: MeasuringPoint) => this.measuringPoints.push(point));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._endSubscriptions.next();
    this._endSubscriptions.complete();
  }

}
```

Here is the docs for RxJS `from()`: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html

This should give your the desired results. Let me know if it doesn't. Cheers!